# Exact border color and width of standard/system QLineEdit?

Tags: pyqt, qt5

Does anyone know the border color of a standard/system QLineEdit?  Black is/seems too dark. It looks like some shade of grey, but would like the exact color.

Also, is the border width 1px?

Comment: There is no standard/system colors since it depends on the style, the same on the geometry. what is the output of `print(app.style().metaObject().className())`?

Comment: QWindowsVistaStyle

Comment: For some styles, it isn't really possible to determine certain colours at all since they use a native theme engine which may bypass the palette when drawing. The Windows Vista Style is like that.

Comment: @Dennis This style uses the Windows API for painting so Qt does not know those colors, for more information check the source code: https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15.2/src/plugins/styles/windowsvista/qwindowsvistastyle.cpp#L522

Comment: Personally, I never mess with general fonts, colours, and such like - that should always be the user's choice. If you start trying to impose your own choices, there will always be at least one user who complains that it totally ruins their theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *no* "standard/system" border color nor border size. It depends on:

- the OS;
- the possible styling customization of the OS;
- the Qt Style in use (which might or might not depend on the OS);
- possible customization used with style sheets;

The color *could* be based on the colors of the current palette, but every style (and OS) use those colors in different ways, and in some cases they are even drawn using pixmaps.

The [color roles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) that *might* be used for drawing borders are:

- QPalette.WindowText
- QPalette.Text
- QPalette.Midlight
- QPalette.Dark
- QPalette.Mid
- QPalette.Shadow

The frame width *could* be based on the `PM_DefaultFrameWidth` pixel metric, that can be queried with the following:

```
# within an existing QLineEdit instance

opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionFrame()
self.initStyleOption(opt)
border = opt.lineWidth

# without a QLineEdit, from any other widget
style = self.style()
# or from the app
opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionFrame()
style = QtWidgets.QApplication.style()
border = style.pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_DefaultFrameWidth, opt)
```

But, as said above, the returned colors and values could *not* be consistent with the actual result, also because the style might do some ajdustments and add graphical effects that could increase/decrease the visible border width and change its appearance.